# Скопировать через PHP строки в таблице MySQL со связями

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется следующая таблица:

```
id | title | parent_id
---+-------+----------
1   Cat1    NULL
2   Cat2    NULL
3   Sub1    2
4   Sub2    2
5   Sub3    4
6   Sub4    1
```

Подскажите, как скопировать эти строки так, что у новых строк изменился и parent_id?

Должно получиться так:

```
id | title | parent_id
---+-------+----------
1   Cat1    NULL
2   Cat2    NULL
3   Sub1    2
4   Sub2    2
5   Sub3    4
6   Sub4    1
7   Cat1    NULL
8   Cat2    NULL
9   Sub1    8
10  Sub2    8
11  Sub3    10
12  Sub4    7
```

Уровень вложенности может быть любым.

Comment: продублировать? поочередными запросами, тока так

Comment: Загружаете все в массив, идете по нему рекурсивной функцией, которая берет из него только строки с принятым на входе parent. Запускаете ее изначально с параметром null. Функция пишет в БД по одной строке, получает новый id (см. last_insert_id() если у вас там автоинкремент) и сохраняет его в дополнительное поле в том же массиве строк и вот как раз его используете на будущих итерациях как новое значение для parent_id

Comment: А кто-нибудь может объяснить - почему у людей необузданное желание хранить две, по сути, разные сущности в одной таблице? Почему нельзя завести отдельные таблицы для категорий и для товаров (или что там)? Таблицы платные чтоли?)

Comment: @АлександрБелинский, объясните мне, пожалуйста, где идёт речь о том, что у меня в одной таблице хранится две сущности?

Comment: @rusbear28, ой, извиняюсь, не **две**, там дерево oO Ну если оно так необходимо - то да, согласен, иначе никак. Но сколько я не видел таких штук - они все ужасно медленные, а толку, кроме абстрактной "красивости" - никакой.